# How to Show Bangla Font(UTF-8) in QTextBrowser / QTextEdit?

Tags: c++, qt

When i try to output some Bangla text, it turns out in empty box without showing Bangla/Unicode properly. 
I tried something like this, but it's not showing correctly

```
ui->textBrowser->setText("কেন কেন"));
ui->textEdit->setText("হয় না ক্যান???"));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, go to QtCreator's properties ->Text Editor->Behavior->File Encodings and set "Default encoding" to  "UTF-8".

Second, write something like this:

```
ui->textBrowser->setText(QString::fromUtf8("কেন কেন")));
ui->textEdit->setText(QString::fromUtf8("হয় না ক্যান???")));
```

Third, forget what I just wrote and use [Qt's translation system](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/linguist-manager.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm using QT 5.0.2... I can't find "QtCreator's property" as you specified... :( Can you please help me???

Comment: Sorry, I was inaccurate, I meant 'Tools->Options'.

Comment: The first method isn't working... I'm not familiar with Qt's Translation System. I think it doesn't enable Bangla, is it???

Comment: @Hasib Al Muhaimin It's not automatically translating, that's for sure. What you do is you wrap text in your application with tr(). Look in the QtCreator help for tr(), and follow the link in the help for that function to "Internationalization with Qt".

Comment: @Hasib Al Muhaimin How come, it isn't working? Here is the working example: http://yadi.sk/d/WVtN2BIJ4pbve

Comment: @Amartel, Thanks a lot, but still your working example shows empty black box... :(

Comment: Well, I've tested it on Qt 4.8.4 (unfortunately, I don't have Qt5 installed), so this may not work. Try other method. It was created for translations and should definitely work.